# Why can't I take the cross product of a sparse matrix (dgCMatrix)?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="TrxID Items Quant
Trx1 A 3
Trx1 B 1
Trx1 C 1
Trx2 E 3
Trx2 B 1
Trx3 B 1
Trx3 C 4
Trx4 D 1
Trx4 E 1
Trx4 A 1
Trx5 F 5
Trx5 B 3
Trx5 C 2
Trx5 D 1", header=T)


term_doc <- xtabs(~ TrxID + Items, data=dat, sparse = TRUE)
co_occur <- crossprod(term_doc, term_doc)
diag(co_occur) <- 0
co_occur
```

Until yesterday, I was able to run this code and it would work.  Now I get the following error:

```
> co_occur <- crossprod(term_doc, term_doc)
Error in crossprod(x, y) : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

If I remove sparse = TRUE, the code runs fine (albeit slowly on my actual dataset).  Why can't I take the crossproduct of a sparse matrix anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two functions with the same name from different packages, I think you need `Matrix::crossprod` not `base::crossprod`.